# App crashing when downloading a large file - NSFileHandle seekToEndOfFile

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I have a loop that gets the URLs of a bunch of files (10 small txt files and 1 large image file around 700KB) and runs 'getFile' which creates an NSUrlConnection for each one.

When the app gets to [file seekToEndOfFile] just before [file writeData:data] it crashes with:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSFileHandleOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle seekToEndOfFile]: No such process'
*** First throw call stack:
```

The strange thing is that if I step through the code (i.e. slowly allowing each connection to go and come back) then all files are downloaded fine.  If I just let the app do its thing it crashes.

Here is code for the connections:

```
-(void)getFile {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    [conn start];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSString *fileName = [[response URL] lastPathComponent];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
    [file seekToEndOfFile];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [file seekToEndOfFile]; // crashing here
    [file writeData:data]; 
}
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
              willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Connection is %@", connection);
    [file closeFile];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"error - %@", error);
}
```

Does my app have a problem keeping reference to the outgoing connections?  I had assumed that NSURLConnections, by default, were asynchronous and you would not need to 'keep track' of them?

**EDIT** I have subclassed NSURLConnection and instantiated as below:

```
-(void)getFile {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]];
    FileURLConnection *conn = [[FileURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES ];
    conn.fileName = [fullURL lastPathComponent];
    [conn start];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are downloading several files simultaneously with one delegate. Try subclass `NSURLConnection` connection and add in it proterty `file`, instead delegate's file property. And I think you don't need `[file seekToEndOfFile];`

EDIT:
example subclassed NSURLConnection

```
@interface FileURLConnection: NSURLConnection

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFileHandle *file;

@end
```

Comment: I had assumed that each connection would generate its own version of the delegate (if that makes sense) I'm guessing this isn't the case.  Do you have an example of the sub classed NSURLConnection?

Comment: @Ryan, I have added example.

Comment: OK I think I understand that far.  I have subclassed NSURLConnection with a name of FileURLConnection that has the properties of NSFileHandle *file and NSString *fileName and have used this in place of NSURLConnection.  How do I get the delegates to actually work with the correct connections now?

Comment: @Ryan. Instantiate and assign delegate, same as with original `NSURLConnection`

Comment: I have added the instantiated class in my question, what do I need to do to the delegates to get them to keep track of the individual connections?

Comment: @Ryan use `FileURLConnection` and it's properties instead `NSURLConnection` in delegate methods.

Comment: I have done as you mentioned and I seem to be able to download all the files without the app crashing now.  Not entirely sure how it works but it does work.  Thanks.