# App not downloading files using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I have an app that loops through an array of URLs and downloads all the files in that array (10 small txt files and 1 large image file).  I had the app downloading the files ok before but due to a problem with the large image, I had to subclass NSURLConnection and I think I haven't quite got it right as no files are now being downloaded.

For each item of the array getFiles is passed a URL and run:

```
-(void)getFile:(NSString*)url tag:(NSString*)tag {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    FileURLConnection *connection = [[FileURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES tag:tag];
    if (connection) {
        [receivedData setObject:[NSMutableData data] forKey:connection.tag];
    }
}
```

Here are the NSURLConnection delegates:

```
-(NSMutableData*)dataForConnection:(FileURLConnection*)connection {
    NSMutableData *data = [receivedData objectForKey:connection.tag];
    return data;
}
- (void)connection:(FileURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSMutableData *dataForConnection = [self dataForConnection:(FileURLConnection*)connection];
    [dataForConnection setLength:0];
}
- (void)connection:(FileURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSMutableData *dataForConnection = [self dataForConnection:(FileURLConnection*)connection];
    [dataForConnection appendData:data];
}
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(FileURLConnection *)connection
              willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(FileURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading run");
    NSMutableData *dataForConnection = [self dataForConnection:(FileURLConnection *)connection];
    NSString *fileName = connection.tag;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
    [file seekToEndOfFile];
    [file writeData:dataForConnection];
    [file closeFile];
}
```

**EDIT**: If I NSLog the receivedData (NSDictionary) in getFile it updates the 'tag' object but no data to go with it:

```
"accomodation.txt" = <>;
"future-congress-dates.txt" = <>;
"general-file.txt" = <>;
...
```

I have also tried to NSLog the dataForConnection (NSMutableData) for each delegate but nothing ever gets printed:

```
NSLog(@"dataForConnection %@", dataForConnection);
```

Comment: Your connection starts immediately, and at that point you havent set the empty mutable data in your receivedData object.
Have you tried to start it after you set the empty data?

Also, it might be simpler to just use
    - (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
method of NSData to write the data to a file.

Comment: Ok what do I need to move where?  Also, I am looking up writeToFile now, to see if I can get it to work in my example.

Comment: Try this:

FileURLConnection *connection = [[FileURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO tag:tag];
    if (connection) {
        [receivedData setObject:[NSMutableData data] forKey:connection.tag];
        [connection start];
    }

Comment: Ah I see.  Ok, I tried that and still no files downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I surrender.
There is full code:

FileURLConnection:

```
@interface FileURLConnection: NSURLConnection

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFileHandle *file;

@end
```

getFile function:

```
-(void)getFile {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]];
    FileURLConnection *conn = [[FileURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}
- (void)connection:(FileURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSString *fileName = [[response URL] lastPathComponent];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    connection.file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
}
- (void)connection:(FileURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [connection.file writeData:data]; 
}
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(FileURLConnection *)connection
              willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(FileURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Connection is %@", connection);
    [connection.file closeFile];
}
- (void)connection:(FileURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"error - %@", error);
}
```

Original question: [App crashing when downloading a large file - NSFileHandle seekToEndOfFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986815/app-crashing-when-downloading-a-large-file-nsfilehandle-seektoendoffile/21987248?noredirect=1#comment33324408_21987248)

Comment: Hi again, the reason I had to ask the question once more is that after implementing your answer before the code appeared to work fine. After repeated testing though I would get the same error (intermittently) as before: '*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle seekToEndOfFile]: No such process'.  How does this code 'know' what connection is going off and which one is coming back?  There seems to be no intensification for the data being received and the file it needs to be saved to (which was the original problem I think?).

Comment: This is also why I changed the code to include 'tags' that other SO questions seemed to point to as a solution to the problem, although I couldn't find an example that worked in my case - probably a mistake I made but I am trying to get to the bottom of it.